# React state value shown undefined after setInterval execution finished

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build Typing Master sort of web application. I am calling setInterval function inside useEffect hook, which returns clearInterval when the timeElapsed is 40 seconds. However after the timer gets expired I am getting undefined for the values of state variable which I have already defined. I am not able to find the issue elsewhere hence I came here. I have pasted my code and the error message screenshot as well. The line mentioned in the error message can be found as I have used comments for that. Kindly help. Here is my code.

```
//line number 17
const [testInfo, setTestInfo] = useState({
timeElapsed: 0,
paragraphFormed: "",
totalKeysPressed: 0,
WPM: 0,
accuracy: 0,});

 useEffect(() => {
const interval = setInterval(() => {
  setTestInfo((preVal) => {
    if (MAX_TIME - preVal.timeElapsed == 0) {
      return clearInterval(interval);
    }
    return {
      ...preVal,
      timeElapsed: preVal["timeElapsed"] + 1,
      WPM: calculateWPM(preVal.paragraphFormed, preVal.timeElapsed),
      accuracy: calculateAccuracy(
        preVal.totalKeysPressed,
        preVal.paragraphFormed.length
      ),
    };
  });
}, 1000);}, []);




 const keyDownHandler = (event) => {
let curLetter = "";
let curtestInfo = {};
//line number 86
setTestInfo((preVal) => {
  if (event.keyCode === 32) {
    if (matchFound(formedCurWord, wordList[wordIndex])) {
      setFormedCurWord("");
      setTestInfo((preVal) => {
        return {
          ...preVal,
          totalKeysPressed: preVal["totalKeysPressed"] + 1,
        };
      });
      setwordIndex((preVal) => {
        return preVal + 1;
      });
      curLetter = " ";
      console.log("space pressed: ", formedCurWord);
      console.log("space pressed: ", preVal["paragraphFormed"]);
      return {
        ...preVal,
        paragraphFormed: preVal["paragraphFormed"].concat(curLetter),
      };
    }
  } else if (event.keyCode === 8) {
    console.log("backspace pressed");
    setFormedCurWord((preVal) => {
      return preVal.slice(0, -1);
    });
    curLetter = "";
    if (formedCurWord !== "") {
      return {
        ...preVal,
        paragraphFormed: preVal["paragraphFormed"].slice(0, -1),
      };
    } else {
      console.log("backspace pressed: ", formedCurWord);
    }
  } else if (allowedKey.includes(event.keyCode)) {
    console.log("you know a valid key is pressed");
    setTestInfo((preVal) => {
      return {
        ...preVal,
        totalKeysPressed: preVal["totalKeysPressed"] + 1,
      };
    });
    setTotalKeysPressed((preVal) => {
      return preVal + 1;
    });
    curLetter = event.key;
    setFormedCurWord((preVal) => {
      return preVal.concat(curLetter);
    });
    //this is line number 139
    return {
      ...preVal,
      paragraphFormed: preVal["paragraphFormed"].concat(curLetter),
    };
  }

  return {
    ...preVal,
    paragraphFormed: preVal["paragraphFormed"].concat(curLetter),
  };
});};
```

[image]

Comment: You are using `preVal` outside of the setState callback

Comment: But it was working till setInterval was alive. Once that expired I got this error. Could this still be the reason @Konrad ?

Comment: return clearInterval is explicitly setting your state to undefined. Try `clearInerval(); return prevVal;`. Your other problem is that `interval` is not in scope in the interval callback. Instead you'll probably want to have `interval` at a higher scope, like `const intervalRef = useRef();`

Comment: You are setting a state in the callback of another setstate. It does not look good to me. You are calling setFormedCurWord and setTestInfo inside setTestInfo callback

Comment: @windowsill I did what you asked `clearInterval(interval); return preVal;` and it solved my two problems. 
1) I am no longer getting preVal not defined . 
2) I was rending the testInfo state on my component. For that as well i was getting `undefined` once the timer got over.
Could you tell me. Why it solved my problem.

Comment: @OktayYuzcan Thanks. Upon your suggestion I noticed that the code was poorly written. So I rearranged few stuffs as well.

Comment: Whatever you return from the state setting function will be the value of the new state. If you return `undefined` then the state will be `undefined`. `clearInterval()` is undefined.